# Specifying the range used by VBA macro in excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with a grid of about 10 columns. 11th column in the sheet does some calculations using the data in those 10 columns and saves the result. After adding a new column in between the initial 10 columns, my range is changed. So, now I have to post the result in 12th column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   ' Check if change is made to the correct range of cells.
   Dim Results As Variant

   'Defaults while sheet only used in Rotterdam
   mGravityUnit = UnitDensity
   mVolumeUnit = UnitCubicMetres
   mTempUnit = UnitCelcius


With Application
    If Not (.Intersect(Target, Range("BargeOpenTemp")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("BargeOpenDens")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("BargeCloseTemp")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("BargeCloseDens")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("BargeGrossVolOpen")) Is Nothing And .Intersect(Target, Range("BargeGrossVolClose")) Is Nothing) Then
        ' Change in Volume Temp or Density
        Dim ThisRow As Integer, VCF As Double
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Not (Cells(ThisRow, 3) = "" Or Cells(ThisRow, 11) = "") Then
            Results = VCF_Calculation(Cells(ThisRow, 3), mTempUnit, Cells(ThisRow, 11), mGravityUnit, mVolumeUnit)
            '         Results = VCF_Calc(Cells(ThisRow, 3), Cells(ThisRow, 10), mGravityUnit, 15, 0)
            Cells(ThisRow, 12) = Results
            'Range("BargeVCFOpen").Value = Results(1)
            'Range("BargeVCFClose").Value = Results(1)
        Else
            Cells(ThisRow, 12) = ""
        End If
        'If closing reading has already been entered then re-calculate the clocing VCF as theoretical Density may have changed.
        If ThisRow < 25 Then
            ThisRow = Target.Row + 20
            If Not (Cells(ThisRow, 3) = "" Or Cells(ThisRow, 11) = "") Then
                Results = VCF_Calculation(Cells(ThisRow, 3), mTempUnit, Cells(ThisRow, 11), mGravityUnit, mVolumeUnit)
                '             Results = VCF_Calc(Cells(ThisRow, 3), Cells(ThisRow, 10), mGravityUnit, 15, 0)
                Cells(ThisRow, 12) = Results
                'Range("BargeVCFOpen").Value = Results(1)
                'Range("BargeVCFClose").Value = Results(1)
            Else
                Cells(ThisRow, 12) = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

This is the existing code, that I changed, and incremented the column indexes.

Sadly, this does not work, as the line below throws an out of range exception.

`If Not (.Intersect(Target, Range("BargeOpenTemp")) Is Nothing`

Clearly, I have to update the target somewhere in the excel. But I can't seem to find the same anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Found how to do that change. Just required selecting the range in the top left corner, and updating the cell numbers.